# Problem in connecting Visual Studio C# to MS Access via file browsing

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to add data source using MS Access file (.mdb) in C# Visual Studio,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1YDf.png)

my problem is that I cant seem to find the browse button to locate my DB Access file. I've tried uninstalling VS Community 2019 replacing it with VS Comm 2015 but the browse button is still not showing

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the ConnectionString row?

Comment: I've tried but it gives me an error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Answer (score 0):

First, if you using Access x32, you MUST force the project settings to x86.

Here:

[image]

If you don't have a x86 config, then in above click on configuration manager and add + create a x86 config. Again: you MUST set the project to x86.

[image]

In above, select new and then this:

[image]

Then ok, and now we have this:

[image]

NOW you can set and choose x86.

eg this:

[image]

YOU MUST DO THE ABOVE!!! Access is a x32 bit application, and thus you must run + force your project to run as x86 code. On the other hand, we are now starting to see office default installs to x64 bits, and then you should consider forcing your project to x64 bits

FYI: if you ARE to run as x64 bits, then you MUST USE ACE data engine, you can NOT use JET DATA engine, since it only comes in x32 flavors.

Next up, adding a connection.

If the file is mdb, and NOT accDB file format? Then I susggest you use JET when you connect. However, if you want to support both mdb and accDB, then you MUST (should) choose ACE data engine.

Ok, now with the above out of the way, then lets setup a conneciton.

In your case, it looks like you attempting to use a mdb file.

So, in the connecting builder.

Project->project properties, we have this under settings:

[image]

In above, we click on connection builder. (and this is quite much the same from any connection wizard you build - but you might as well build a system wide conneciton setting, right????

ok, now:
[image]

[image]

Now, at this point you CAN hit browse, but read on!!!

[image]

However, do you want to use JET (x32 bits only, MUST use mdb file)
Or do you want to use ACE - (can be x64, can use both mdb, and accDB, but SOME older mdb files will not work. if you using mdb file, then use JET).

So, before you hit browse to file in above, click on the advanced button, and choose JET in place of ACE here:

You see that in the advanced tab (I think it defualts to JET, but still CHECK this setting).

[image]

So, we choose JET.

Now we back to previous panel, and you can hit browse, and you selected your file.

eg this:

[image]

Ok, and you can use test connection. But as noted, you MUST have setup and forced the project to x86 before all this will work.

So, drop a button, say a data grid onto a form,

And we have this code now:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessTest))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";

            using (OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                dataGridView1.DataSource = rstData;

            }
        }
    }
```

And we see this:

[image]